# Which song is played in Akame ga Kill episode 12 at 20:32?

Tags: music, akame-ga-kill

I seriously couldn't find any existence of thing song at all, please help.

Answer (score 0):

It's a song called Jaegers* by Takumi Iwasaki (イェーガーズ by 岩崎工). You can find it on Spotify [here](https://open.spotify.com/track/4NPYo2pdThY4H4IOeJ088p?si=i8Q28SLlT4G7kab-LqF1Yg).

*Google Translated